# Using Collection Salesforce

Tags: class

Iam new in Salesforce So please help me .I have to write a code in apex to count character of string For example "APPLE" so it count A=1,P=2,L=1,E=1.and one thing more a=A ,b=B ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, that this logic should be case-insensitive. Try this code:

```
public static Map<String, Integer> countCharacters(String toCount){
    Map<String, Integer> result = new Map<String, Integer>();
    for(String symbol: toCount.split('')) {
        String value = symbol.toLowerCase();
        Integer counter = 0;
        if(result.containsKey(value)){
            counter = result.get(value);
        }
        ++counter;
        result.put(value, counter);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then result of

```
String  check='Apple';
System.debug(countCharacters(check));
```

is

> DEBUG|{a=1, e=1, l=1, p=2}

Comment: when i put    String  check='Apple';
                     System.debug(countCharacters(check));   in anonmous window it show    Line: 2, Column: 14
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: countCharacters(String)

Comment: @Atul  you need to copy chountCharacters method to anonymous apex as well. I am sure the following link will help you https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_execute_anonymous.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Answer (score 3):

You can use a map and split to get this data:

```
Map<String, Integer> values = new Map<String, Integer>();
for(String value: source.split('')) {
    String key = value.toUpperCase();
    Integer counter = values.get(key);
    if(counter == null) {
        counter = 0;
    }
    values.put(key, counter+1);
}
```

Comment: best answer@sfdcfox

Comment: hm, your code is not compiling, because of "char" reserved word. And I think Integer value = char.get(key); should be Integer value = values.get(key);

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy Yeah, I should have proofread my code. Updated